# List<byte[]> to single byte[]

Tags: java

```
List<byte[]> listOfByteArrays;
```

I want to get all the `byte[]` stored in this `List` to just one `byte[]` by appending all elements in the `List`. I know one way to do it and that is by using `System.arrayCopy()`but using that inside a loop is going to be a little messy `(temporary variables and byte[] arrays)`. Tried finding a better way of doing it but couldn't. Any pointers? Any external API's I can use?

Comment: You can use ArraysUtils from apache commons, the method addAll from that class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One-liner with [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Bytes.concat(listOfByteArray.toArray(new byte[0][]));
```

or a little bit longer (spares one byte array allocation which occurs inside `toArray` in the shorter version)

```
Bytes.concat(listOfByteArray.toArray(new byte[listOfByteArray.size()][]));
```

Comment: Is this deprecated? I can't seem to find Bytes class in com.google.common.io

Answer (score 11):

Try using [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out= new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
```

in loop

```
out.write(eachBytearray);
```

After loop

```
byte result[] = out.toByteArray( );
```

Answer (score 6):

Why would you need temporary arrays?

- Make one pass through your list, sum the lengths of the individual arrays.
- Create a single array large enough to hold them all
- Make a second pass through your list, using `System.arraycopy` to copy the array from the list to its appropriate place in the target array. (You would need to keep track of the offset in the target array, obviously.)

Answer (score 3):

This is easy enough to write from scratch:

```
int length = 0;
for (byte[] ba : listOfByteArrays) {
    length += ba.length
}


byte[] total = new byte[length];

int index = 0;
for (byte[] ba : listOfByteArrays) {
    for (byte b : ba) {
        total[index++] = b;
    }
}
```

`total` is the desired byte array.

Comment: I'll bet you a lot that System.arrayCopy as suggested in the other answers are quite a bit faster than this. The code is sound otherwise.

Comment: @Xabster I doubt the difference will be noticeable. If the OP has benchmarked both variants extensively and has arrived at the conclusion that `System.arrayCopy` is consistently faster, *then* there is a reason to use one over the other. Otherwise, it's undoubtedly a premature optimization.

Comment: If he hasn't written it yet, it's not premature optimization. It's just "doing it right the first time around". :oP

Comment: @Xabster Changing the way he *would* write it for the sole reason that the `System.arrayCopy` variant might be slightly faster falls under the category of premature optimization, IMO. If the OP finds `System.arrayCopy` easier to write/read/manage (which, judging by his post, I get the impression that he does not), then he is free to write it that way the first time around. I wrote this particular snippet the way I did simply because I found it more intuitive and easier to follow, and I certainly wasn't going to sacrifice that by using `System.arrayCopy`.

Comment: Alright. I guess I just have to accept your definition of premature optimization. In any case, I just tested and I get 61ms time for 10000 arrays of average size 10000 (that's 100 million bytes total in 10000 arrays) for your code, and 41ms for my own code using arrayCopy. I agree that such small differences on such big numbers is highly unlike to matter for OP. I do however suspect the compiler to optimize your code into a sort of array copy.

Answer (score 0):

I would loop the list and sum up the lengths of the arrays in the list. Create a byte[] that holds them all. Loop and copy with System.arrayCopy() into the appropriate indexes.

I don't think a 3rd party library is warranted for just such a thing as what you describe.

You seem to know how to code it, so I'll leave out example code.